# How do I convert this function from C to C#?

Tags: c#, c, date

I am halfway done with converting this function from c to c# but I am totally lost as to what the middle computational line does.

```
            y -= m < 3;
```

C Version

```
 int DayOfWeek(int d, int m, int y)
        {
            static int t[] = { 0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4 };
            y -= m < 3;
            return (y + y / 4 - y / 100 + y / 400 + t[m - 1] + d) % 7;
        }
```

C# Version

```
 int DayOfWeek(int d, int m, int y)
        {
            int[] t = { 0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4 };  
            y -= m < 3;
            return (y + y / 4 - y / 100 + y / 400 + t[m - 1] + d) % 7;
        }
```

1) I understand y -= m is equivalent to y = y - m but what does "<" do? Is it an expression?
2) How do I convert the rest of this to c#?

Thank you everyone, for clarification this is for a degree program.

Comment: You do know that C# has a very reliable DateTime type, right?

Comment: In C `m < 3` evaluates to `0` or `1`. The line `y -= m < 3;` is equivalent to `if(m < 3) { y--; }`

Comment: You can call `Convert.ToInt32(m < 3)`

Comment: @hvd: Already noted that. So it is `y -= m < 3 ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: `y -=m < 3 ? 1 : 0;` should work, but maybe use this opportunity to make the code more readable for humans and write it as: `if (m < 3) y--;`...

Comment: `y -= (m < 3).CompareTo(false);`

Comment: @L.B - That does get the obfuscation bonus.

Comment: @obe - of course, but the OP needs to see the direct conversion too. Weathervane already posted the better answer. Plus him.

Comment: @HenkHolterman thank you, I don't like ternary operators anyway, they do not flow through my mind nicely.

Comment: @L.B That would be wrong even if it weren't horrible. [`CompareTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz786x34(v=vs.110).aspx) is only specified to return a positive value, it need not be `1`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - right, I missed his answer somehow :) anyway I agree that it's good to show the correlation. I think it's also worthwhile to mention the rationale for preferring the `if` syntax over the `? :` operator.

Comment: @WeatherVane - You can post it as an answer. Comments don't count on SO.

Comment: I am surprised people took it serious :)  I just wanted to add some humor...

Comment: @L.B Oh, don't worry, I didn't think you were serious about it. :)

Comment: @ICodeNow this formula `y -= (m < 3);` has been added to take into account that the additional day of leap year is the **February 29th** !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
y -= (m < 3) ? 1 : 0;
```

or more readibly

```
if (m < 3) y -= 1;
```

or even

```
if (m < 3) --y;
```

It's some C code using the fact that conditionals return 1 or 0 as a value. Fix as shown.

Edit: I now see the comments saying this code is obfuscated. I guess I'm such an old C hat I found it immediately obvious on reading it, not that I recommend writing it that way.

Or we can do this thing the really ovbious way:

```
int DayOfWeek(int d, int m, int y) => (new DateTime(y, m, d)).DayOfWeek;
```

Comment: Ah so the same as a ternary operator in PHP!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am unfamiliar with C# syntax, but in C

```
m < 3
```

evaluates to `0` or `1`. The line

```
y -= m < 3;
```

is equivalent to

```
if(m < 3) { y--; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int DayOfWeek(int d, int m, int y)
{
   var dt = new DateTime(y,m,d);
   return (int) dt.DayOfWeek;
}
```

Comment: Dupe! (I would rather use a private message but it exists not)